# How to auto refresh API data in react JS?

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I trying to create weather app and use open weather API and it's work fine. Now I need to refresh data every 5 minute automatically.
This is my code :

```
   const weatherApi = {
  getTodayData(city) {
    //Get the CURRENT data
    //console.log(API_URL_CURRENT + "&q=" + city);
    return fetch(API_URL_CURRENT + "&q=" + city)
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => ({
        temp: parseInt(data.main.temp, 0),
        humidity : parseInt(data.main.humidity , 0),
        temp_max: parseInt(data.main.temp_max, 0),
        wind: parseInt(data.wind.speed, 0),
        temp_min: parseInt(data.main.temp_min, 0),
        weatherDescription: data.weather[0].description,
        weatherIcon: this.getIconUrl(data.weather[0].icon),
        country: data.sys.country,
        timezone: data.timezone,
        time: this.formatDate(data.dt, data.timezone, "time"),
        weekday: this.formatDate(data.dt, data.timezone, "weekday"),
        city: data.name,
      }))
      .catch(error => {
        return [];
      });

  },
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getTodayData();
    setInterval(this.getTodayData, 18000); // 3 minutes in milliseconds. 3*60*1000
  },
}
```

I trying to create that with componentDidMount but it's doesn't work.

Comment: For starters, `18` is not "3 minutes in milliseconds".  Aside from that, in what specific way does this fail?  Are there any errors on the browser's development console?  When you debug, is the operation repeated each interval?  Is the AJAX request made on each interval?  What specifically happens?

Comment: Put 180000 in the setInterval

Comment: @David 18 for test and I know that not 3 minutes. When run this code noting happen and nothing change and no error.

Comment: @NishargShah My issue is noting happen in timeout

Comment: @SajjadShiasi: "Nothing happens" is a non-starter.  You need to debug to find out what does happen.  For all we know this component never even loads or this code is never invoked.  What is `weatherApi` and where is it ever used?  Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem and indicate what debugging you have done to narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the reason nothing happens is because you are not sending a city as an argument to the getTodayData function, and maybe this would work:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.getTodayData();
    setInterval(() => {
        this.getTodayData('Paris')
    }, 3*60*1000);
}
```

Comment: `getTodayData` function is work fine and city pass to function. when I need to refresh and update data nothing happend even when use `componentDidMount`

Answer (score 0):

Here it is working please check and as @dandan said the problem is you are not passing the city in the function

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-hodgkin-olwp4?file=/src/App.js